# Rethrowing inner exception of an AggregateException

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, aggregateexception

Let's say I have an Interface:

```
interface A {
    string Do();
}
```

and then I implement this interface in a class. The implementation requires some async operations. Something like the following:

```
class B : A {
    public string Do() {
        return Task1().Result;
    }

    private async Task<string> Task1() {
        var str = await Task2();

        return str + "task1";
    }

    private async Task<string> Task2() {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(new Uri("http://test.com")));
        }
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to return, to the external calling code, the first exception that occurs in the async operations chain? Is the following a good approach?

```
public string Do() {
    try {
        return Task1().Result;
    } catch (AggregateException ex) {
        Exception inner = ex;
        while(inner.InnerException != null) {
            inner = inner.InnerException;
        }

        throw inner;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, through the `while`, I think you want to throw the first exception in `AggregateException`
To do that, you can use [Flatten](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.flatten.aspx)

> Flattens an AggregateException instances into a single, new instance.

It helps to put the exceptions in "the same hierarchy", you can then simply call `FirstOrDefault` to get the first exception.

Supposed this code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
        async () =>
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => { throw new Exception("inner"); },
                TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

            throw new Exception("outer");
        }).Wait();
    }
```

The stucture of exceptions likes

```
AggregateException
    Exception: outer
    AggregateException
       Exception: inner
```

With `Flatten`, I can get `inner`

```
catch(AggregateException ex)
{
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions.FirstOrDefault().Message);
}
```

but without `Flatten`, I get `AggregateException`, which isn't correct

```
catch(AggregateException ex)
{
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions.FirstOrDefault().Message);
}
```

With your case, this line can help you get the first exception

```
ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions.FirstOrDefault().Message
```

You have also the method [Handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.handle(v=vs.110).aspx), which help you handle the exception inside `AggregateException`

```
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    ex.Handle(x =>
    {
        if (x is UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            //the exception you interested
            throw x;           
        }
        // Other exceptions will not be handled here.
        //some action i.e log
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: But it's a good idea to return the first exception to the caller, right?

Comment: For me, I handle the exception that I care, that means I throw it. Others, I skip. Look at the answer update.